# Centering content in Bootstrap 5 OffCanvas Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

how can I center all of the content in a offcanvas navbar in bootstrap version 5.2? I added "d-flex justify-content-center" class to the container-fluid wrapper of navigation. Even though it aligns content in mobile version, pc version is still not aligned center.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you have a screen grab or mock of what you want the output to look like on a PC?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your actual goals for centering... `text-center`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light fixed-top text-center">
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light fixed-top text-center">
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```